# Implement phone directory using two tries

Tags: string, algorithm, trie

```
    I have encountered an interview question
    “Implement a phone directory using Data Structures”
```

I want to solve it using tries.By solving it with tries,I tried using two tries,one for name                                                             and another for phone number,
        but I faced a difficulty .
        Suppose ,I have to add three entries(  AB  “112” BC  ”124”   CD  ”225”)
        Then if I query the name for number “225”,how do I return CD.
        that is,how these two tries will be linked .

```
    One approach I was thinking was taking two pointers in both the tries.
    These pointers will point to the first and last word in the other trie.
    For example,if the structures are as follows:

    Struct nametrie                            
    {                                                       
     Struct nametrie *child[26];
     struct phonetrie*head,*tail;
     struct phonetrie*root;       

     -----------    
    }                                                       

      Struct phonetrie
     {
             struct phonetrie*child[9];
             struct nametrie*head,*tail;
             struct nametrie*root;
        ----------- 
      }


    Then for AB “112”,  
    Name trie willstore head(1) and tail (2).
```

But I think this approach will not work for duplicate entries(one name and multiple numbers.)

```
Can someone please explain a good approach.I am not looking for code but good understanding of approach,may be via diagram or algorithm.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know C so I cant comment in your code.

The idea of using tries is valid.

you seems to be missing what data the nodes can hold in tries

the node in trees has 2 main components

1. the data it has which can be anytype
2. list of childen (or left , right childeren) or any combination of children

what we will do here is that we will add another field to each node and call it the value "theValue"

So the trie node will look like this

```
Class TrieNode{
public char theChar;
public String theValue;
public List<TrieNode> children;
}
```

So for forward lookup (name to phone) you construct one Trie and on the node that match entry in the directory you will set theValue to that entrie.

you will need to create 2nd trie to  do the same for reverse lookup (phone to name)

So to give you example how it will look like for this data it will be

( AB “112” AC ”124” ACD ”225”)

```
//create nodes
TrieNode root = new TrieNode();
TrieNode A = new TrieNode();
A.theChar = 'A';
TrieNode B = new TrieNode();
A.theChar = 'B';
TrieNode C = new TrieNode();
A.theChar = 'C';
TrieNode C2 = new TrieNode();
A.theChar = 'C';
TrieNode D = new TrieNode();
A.theChar = 'D';
//link nodes together
root.children = new ArrayList<>();
root.children.add(A);
A.children = new ArrayList<>();
A.children.add(B);
A.children.add(C);
B.children = new ArrayList<>();
B.children.add(C2);
//fill the data
B.theValue = "112";
C.theValue = "124";
C2.theValue = "225";
```

now you can easy traverse this Trie and when you reach a node and whant to check the value just read theValue

i hope it is clear

Comment: :For reverse look up,it will not work,that is from number to name.For this you have to create another trie.If you include value field in that trie also,then the same value is stored twice.Once in trie from from root to leaf node and other time in value field in second trie

Comment: @KIMchi That is exactly correct. so you will have duplication but you will get fast search access in both cases

Comment: :can it also be done without duplications?Any suggestions on that?

Comment: I cant think of anyway specially that although we create 2 tries the data the nodes are pointing to is different in each trie. and based on my understanding this is the norm in tries (you will have more than 1 trie with duplication for the gain of partial search and search speed)

Comment: :I have one more query,suppose there are two numbers associated with a same name,how will this be resolved?

Comment: one more solution i find is Blend of both trie and Hashing
 you can create a trie initially which can be used to fetch the correct bucket 
 in the hash table which has the result and later you can do binary search in the set of values 
 in the respective bucket and fetch the result.

Comment: for the 2 numbers associated with 1 name . you can always change the type of the theValue to any class you wish to have or another easy solution is to change the value to String List.